# Avoid Race Condition Creating StorageFolder

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am unit testing a new Win8 Store app and noticed a race condition I want to avoid.  So I am looking for a way to avoid this race condition.

I have a class that when instantiated calls a method to be sure it has a local StorageFolder.  My unit test simply instantiates the object and tests if the folder is there.  Sometime the folder is not and sometimes it is so I believe this to be a race condition because the CreateFolderAsync is asynchronous (obviously).

```
public class Class1
{
    StorageFolder _localFolder = null;

    public Class1()
    {
        _localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        _setUpStorageFolders();
    }

    public StorageFolder _LocalFolder
    {
        get
        {
            return _localFolder;
        }

    }


    async void _setUpStorageFolders()
    {
        try
        {
            _localFolder = await _localFolder.CreateFolderAsync("TestFolder", CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

My Unit Test Looks Like This:

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void _LocalFolder_Test()
    {
        Class1 ke = new Class1();


        // TODO: Fix Race Condition 
        StorageFolder folder = ke._LocalFolder;

        string folderName = folder.Name;

        Assert.IsTrue(folderName == "TestFolder");

    }
```

Comment: Is this the only test in the set?  Are there any other tests? If so are you setting up and clearing down between each one?

Comment: Why create the folder async? It's not a so much time-consuming operation that will inflict a dramatic performance penalty

Comment: Yes just one test for now.

Comment: What is the pattern to do this synchronously?

Comment: My mistake, StorageFolder has only Async methods (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR227230)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Iboshuizen suggested, I would do this synchronously.  This can be done with `async`, `task`, and `await`.  There is a gotcha - the setup cannot be done inside the constructor of `Class1` because constructors do not support async/ await.  Because of this `SetUpStorageFolders` is now public, and is called from the test method.

```
public class Class1
{
    StorageFolder _localFolder = null;

    public Class1()
    {
        _localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                // call to setup removed here because constructors
                // do not support async/ await keywords
    }

    public StorageFolder _LocalFolder
    {
        get
        {
            return _localFolder;
        }

    }

      // now public... (note Task return type)
    async public Task SetUpStorageFolders()
    {
        try
        {
            _localFolder = await _localFolder.CreateFolderAsync("TestFolder", CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
 // note the signature change here (async + Task)
 [TestMethod]
    async public Task _LocalFolder_Test()
    {
        Class1 ke = new Class1();
        // synchronous call to SetupStorageFolders - note the await
        await ke.SetUpStorageFolders();

        StorageFolder folder = ke._LocalFolder;

        string folderName = folder.Name;

        Assert.IsTrue(folderName == "TestFolder");
    }
```